# Scrape Table from web page in c#

Tags: c#, html, datatable, scrape

What is the best approach to build a function to scrape a html table on a webpage into a variable.

I want to be able to pass it some unique identifier (like table ID or something) and it will return all the data into something like a DataTable.

Comment: It wasn't as easy as I wanted it to be, so here was what I came up with: http://mdukehall.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/convert-a-blog-website-into-a-sql-data-dump/

Comment: @Michael No approach is fool proof -- even with a third party tool. HTML has very loose standards when it comes to closing tags, meaning that there is no guarentee that your "XML" tree will be formed correctly, so a lot of scraping can be tedious and trial and error prone. Sometimes the best approach is to simply find a static element near or at the data on the page and work your logic around it. Splitting, parsing, etc., until you get your result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) to parse the HTML and extract the table data.

With HAP now supporting Linq you could start with something like this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = ...
var myTable = doc.DocumentNode
                 .Descendants("table")
                 .Where(t =>t.Attributes["id"].Value == someTableId)
                 .FirstOrDefault();

if(myTable != null)
{
    ///further parsing here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string htmlCode = "";
htmlCode = driver.PageSource.ToString();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);

var gvTender = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table")
             .Where(table => table.Attributes.Contains("id"))
             .FirstOrDefault(table => table.Attributes["id"].Value == "ctl00_cphContentArea_gvTenders");

List<HtmlNode> rows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr").Skip(10).ToList();
    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        try
        {
            rowCount++;
            if (rowCount >= 16)
                break;

            List<HtmlNode> cells = row.SelectNodes("th|td").ToList();


            string s1 = cells[0].InnerText.ToString().Replace("\r\n", "").Trim();
            string s2 = cells[1].InnerText.ToString().Replace("\r\n", "").Trim();
            string s3 = cells[2].InnerText.ToString();
            string s4 = cells[3].InnerText.ToString();
            string s5 = cells[4].InnerText.ToString();
            string s6 = cells[5].InnerText.ToString();
            string s7 = cells[6].InnerText.ToString();
            string s8 = cells[7].InnerText.ToString();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
    //Developed By -Ramdas Chavan(Datamatics)
```